# Selecting unique records based on date of effect, ending on date of discontinue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an interesting conundrum and I am using SQL Server 2012 or SQL Server 2016 (T-SQL obviously).  I have a list of products, each with their own UPC code.  These products have a discontinue date and the UPC code gets recycled to a new product after the discontinue date.  So let's say I have the following in the Item_UPCs table:

```
    Item Key | Item Desc |     UPC    | UPC Discontinue Date
      123456 | Shovel    | 0009595959 | 2018-04-01
      123456 | Shovel    | 0007878787 | NULL
      234567 | Rake      | 0009595959 | NULL
```

As you can see, I have a UPC that gets recycled to a new product.  Unfortunately, I don't have an effective date for the item UPC table, but I do in an items table for when an item was added to the system.  But let's ignore that.

Here's what I want to do:

- For every inventory record up to the discontinue date, show the unique UPC associated with that date.  An inventory record consists of the "Inventory Date", the "Purchase Cost", the "Purchase Quantity", the "Item Description", and the "Item UPC".
- Once the discontinue date is over with (e.g.: it's the next day), start showing only the UPC that is in effect.
- Make sure that no duplicate data exists and the UPCs are truly being "attached" to each row per whatever the date is in the query.

Here is an example of the inventory details table:

```
Inv_Key | Trans_Date | Item_Key | Purch_Qty | Purch_Cost
    123 | 2018-05-12 |   123456 |     12.00 | 24.00
    108 | 2018-03-22 |   123456 |      8.00 | 16.00
    167 | 2018-07-03 |   234567 |     12.00 | 12.00
```

An example query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     s.SiteID
    ,id.Item_Key
    ,iu.Item_Desc
    ,iu.Item_Department
    ,iu.Item_Category
    ,iu.Item_Subcategory
    ,iu.UPC
    ,iu.UPC_Discontinue_Date
    ,id.Trans_Date
    ,id.Purch_Cost
    ,id.Purch_Qty
FROM Inventory_Details id
INNER JOIN Item_UPCs iu ON iu.Item_Key = id.Item_Key
INNER JOIN Sites s ON s.Site_Key = id.Site_Key
```

The real query I have is far too long to post here.  It has three CTEs and the resultant query.  This is simply a mockup.  Here is an example result set:

```
Site_ID | Item_Key | Item_Desc | Item_Department | Item_Category |    UPC     | UPC_Discontinue Date | Trans_Date | Purch_Cost | Purch_Qty
   2457 |   123456 | Shovel    | Digging Tools   |       Shovels | 0009595959 | 2018-04-01           | 2018-03-22 |      16.00 |      8.00
   2457 |   123456 | Shovel    | Digging Tools   |       Shovels | 0007878787 | NULL                 | 2018-03-22 |      16.00 |      8.00
   2457 |   234567 | Rakes     | Garden Tools    |         Rakes | 0009595959 | NULL                 | 2018-07-03 |      12.00 |     12.00
   2457 |   123456 | Shovel    | Digging Tools   |       Shovels | 0007878787 | NULL                 | 2018-05-12 |      24.00 |     12.00
```

Do any of you know how I can "assign" a UPC to a specific range of dates in my query and then "assign" an updated UPC to the item for every effective date thereafter?

Many thanks!

Comment: For every *what* record up to the discontinue date?

Comment: Every inventory record.  For instance: there's an inventory date, a purchase amount, a quantity, the item info including description and UPC.

Comment: sorry, but you need to provide your table structures as well.

Comment: The tables are rather large.  What exactly are you wanting that my example query that spits out a resultant table cannot give?  Thanks!

Comment: some useful sample data from the Inventory Table. and your end results. Just have a read here - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query you should be able to improve your question :)

Comment: Thank you, Sudipta.  I will work on this.

Comment: Does my post now reflect better?  Let me know if this is insufficient and I will strive to do better.

Comment: How large are your tables?  What are their rowcounts now and projected to be over the next 5 or so years?

Comment: Hi @iamdave.  My tables are hundreds of thousands of rows right now and go back to mid 2018 but will be perpetual.  They will record data every day for an indefinite period

Comment: So you are aware, in SQL Server terms hundreds of thousands is not *rather large* as you descibed it earlier.  I would go so far as to say it isn't even *big*.

Comment: Ok I see that @iamdave.  It is subjective per organization on what they consider to be a lot of data--especially when the data is perpetual and continually growing--and I have to admit your comment was non-constructive in the way it was phrased.  But I will attempt to quantify future posts with such a measurement.  By the way... my "rather large" comment was denoting that each table structure has dozens or more columns.  It would be difficult to put all of them into this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your current Item_UPC table, you can generate effective start dates from the Discontinue Date using the LAG analytic function:

```
With Effective_UPCs as (
  select [Item_Key]
       , [Item_Desc]
       , [UPC]
       , coalesce(lag([UPC_Discontinue_Date])
           over (partition by [Item_Key]
                     order by coalesce( [UPC_Discontinue_Date]
                                      , datefromparts(9999,12,31))
           ),
           lag([UPC_Discontinue_Date])
           over (partition by [UPC]
                     order by coalesce( [UPC_Discontinue_Date]
                                      , datefromparts(9999,12,31))
         )) [UPC_Start_Date]
       , [UPC_Discontinue_Date]
    from Item_UPCs i
)
select * from Effective_UPCs;
```

Which yields the following **[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/baeee0/7/0)**:

```
| Item_Key | Item_Desc |        UPC | UPC_Start_Date | UPC_Discontinue_Date |
|----------|-----------|------------|----------------|----------------------|
|   123456 |    Shovel | 0007878787 |     2018-04-01 |               (null) |
|   123456 |    Shovel | 0009595959 |         (null) |           2018-04-01 |
|   234567 |      Rake | 0009595959 |     2018-04-01 |               (null) |
```

This function produces a fully open ended interval where both the start and discontinue dates could be null indicating that it's effective for all time. To use this in your query simply reference the `Effective_UPCs` CTE in place of the `Item_UPCs` table and add a couple additional predicates to take the effective dates into consideration:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     s.SiteID
    ,id.Item_Key
    ,iu.Item_Desc
    ,iu.Item_Department
    ,iu.Item_Category
    ,iu.Item_Subcategory
    ,iu.UPC
    ,iu.UPC_Discontinue_Date
    ,id.Trans_Date
    ,id.Purch_Cost
    ,id.Purch_Qty
FROM Inventory_Details id
INNER JOIN Effective_UPCs iu 
   ON iu.Item_Key = id.Item_Key
  and (iu.UPC_Start_Date is null       or iu.UPC_Start_Date < id.Trans_Date)
  and (iu.UPC_Discontinue_Date is null or id.Trans_Date <= iu.UPC_Discontinue_Date)
INNER JOIN Sites s ON s.Site_Key = id.Site_Key
```

Note that the above query uses a partially open range (`UPC_Start_Date` **<** `trans_date` **<=** `UPC_Discontinue_Date` instead of <= for both inequalities) this prevents transactions occurring exactly on the discontinue date from matching both the prior and next `Item_Key` record.  If transactions that occur exactly on the discontinue date should match the new record and not the old simply swap the two inequalities:

```
  and (iu.UPC_Start_Date is null       or iu.UPC_Start_Date <= id.Trans_Date)
  and (iu.UPC_Discontinue_Date is null or id.Trans_Date < iu.UPC_Discontinue_Date)
```

instead of

```
  and (iu.UPC_Start_Date is null       or iu.UPC_Start_Date < id.Trans_Date)
  and (iu.UPC_Discontinue_Date is null or id.Trans_Date <= iu.UPC_Discontinue_Date)
```

Comment: Thank you!  I will test this out and let you know if it works.  Please allow some time for this to occur.  I will mark this as the answer as soon as I can (could be days or longer since I am working on multiple projects).  I appreciate your response!